# ActiveConnection Error

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, asp-classic, database-connection

I am just using sql store procedures inside classic asp to perform queries and data insertions etc. However I seem to be getting errors on the following:

```
.ActiveConnection = db
```

The only error I get is

> error '80004005'

I get this error whenever I try calling a store procedure, whether it be a store procedure in a function file or in the actual file being executed. I seems to work if I put the connection details directly above it  however it then fails for the next store procedure. I have never had this issue before and I can only think it may have something to do with the other process I am carrying out, which is reading data out of a CSV with with the data reader object. Thanks

Comment: What does your code snippet look like?  The provided sample doesn't show anything to go on.

Comment: What database? What's your connection string?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](http://tutorials.aspfaq.com/8000xxxxx-errors/80004005-errors.html) which provides a nice list of different 80004005 error conditions and how to go about fixing them.

As @RogerSpear00 says it is hard to help if you don't post a fuller code snippet.